Docker compose creates Reactjs container, but does not run it
Update - Solved (21 Jul 2024)
I have since debugged the above and managed to configure my frontend DockerFile and compose.yaml to allow me to run my spring-react app in a single docker compose up --build. This docker command was paired with docker compose down --rmi all during my debug process. I did not change my backend-spring DockerFile.
updated compose.yaml
services:
  backend:
    build: backend-spring
    restart: always
    ports:
      - 8080:8080

  frontend:
    build:
      context: frontend-react
    stdin_open: true
    tty: true
    ports:
      - 3000:3000
    depends_on:
      - backend

updated Frontend DockerFile
ARG NODE_VERSION=20.13.1

################################################################################
# Use node image for base image for all stages.
FROM node:${NODE_VERSION}-alpine as base

# Set working directory for all build stages.
WORKDIR /app


################################################################################
# Create a stage for installing production dependecies.
FROM base as deps

# Download dependencies as a separate step to take advantage of Docker's caching.
# Leverage a cache mount to /root/.npm to speed up subsequent builds.
# Leverage bind mounts to package.json and package-lock.json to avoid having to copy them
# into this layer.
RUN --mount=type=bind,source=package.json,target=package.json \
    --mount=type=bind,source=package-lock.json,target=package-lock.json \
    --mount=type=cache,target=/root/.npm \
    npm ci --omit=dev

################################################################################
# Create a stage for building the application.
FROM deps as build

# Download additional development dependencies before building, as some projects require
# "devDependencies" to be installed to build. If you don't need this, remove this step.
RUN --mount=type=bind,source=package.json,target=package.json \
    --mount=type=bind,source=package-lock.json,target=package-lock.json \
    --mount=type=cache,target=/root/.npm \
    npm ci
# Copy package.json so that package manager commands can be used.
COPY package*.json .

RUN npm install

# Copy the rest of the source files into the image.
COPY . .

# Run the build script.
RUN npm run build --omit=dev

################################################################################
# Create a new stage to run the application with minimal runtime dependencies
# where the necessary files are copied from the build stage.
FROM base as final

# Use production node environment by default.
ENV NODE_ENV production

# Copy package.json so that package manager commands can be used.
COPY package.json .

# Copy the production dependencies from the deps stage and also
# the built application from the build stage into the image.
COPY --from=deps /app/node_modules ./node_modules
COPY --from=build /app/build ./build
COPY --from=build /app/public ./public
COPY --from=build /app/src ./src

## Install `serve` to run the application.
RUN npm install -g serve

# Run the application as a non-root user.
USER node

## Expose the port that the application listens on.
EXPOSE 3000
# Run application # switch between npm start (debug) and serve (for production).
#CMD [ "npm", "start" ]
CMD ["serve", "-s", "build"]


Original Question
I am new to Docker and am attempting to have a single compose.yaml for my spring-react app. I created individual Dockerfiles for the backend (spring) and frontend (react) using docker init and some stackoverflow threads during debugging.
.
├── backend-spring
│   ├── ...
│   ├── Dockerfile
├── frontend-react
│   ├── ...
│   └── Dockerfile
├── ...
└── compose.yaml

I am trying to get the app working locally before I attempt deploying it onto AWS.
When I run docker compose up -d in my root directory, it states that both the backend and frontend docker containers are created. However, when I run docker container ls, only the spring backend container appears. This is an issue as I am not able to access my react app via localhost (since it is not running).
Image of docker compose up -d result 
The frontend-react container does not appear when I run docker container ls - why is this so?
I suspect that the issue maybe the frontend Dockerfile, and I have tinkered with the RUN/CMD commands of my frontend-react Dockerfile to no avail.
The React app runs when I manually run serve -s build or npm start in the directory, so the app has no issues. I would like the end result of just running one docker compose up -d command to have both my frontend and backend running. I have verified that I can access my spring backend api on localhost after the docker compose command.
Greatly appreciate your help.

compose.yaml
services:
  backend:
    build: backend-spring
    restart: always
    ports:
      - 8080:8080

  frontend:
    build:
      context: frontend-react
#      target: development # defines the stage to build as defined inside a multi-stage Dockerfile. Since backend-spring Dockerfile is only single stage, commented this out.
    stdin_open: true
    tty: true
    ports:
      - 3000:3000
    volumes:
      - /frontend-react/src
      - /frontend-react/node_modules
    depends_on:
      - backend

Frontend DockerFile
# syntax=docker/dockerfile:1

# Dockerfile reference guide at
# https://docs.docker.com/go/dockerfile-reference/

ARG NODE_VERSION=20.13.1

################################################################################
# Use node image for base image for all stages.
FROM node:${NODE_VERSION}-alpine as base

# Set working directory for all build stages.
WORKDIR /usr/src/app


################################################################################
# Create a stage for installing production dependecies.
FROM base as deps

# Download dependencies as a separate step to take advantage of Docker's caching.
# Leverage a cache mount to /root/.npm to speed up subsequent builds.
# Leverage bind mounts to package.json and package-lock.json to avoid having to copy them
# into this layer.
RUN --mount=type=bind,source=package.json,target=package.json \
    --mount=type=bind,source=package-lock.json,target=package-lock.json \
    --mount=type=cache,target=/root/.npm \
    npm ci --omit=dev

################################################################################
# Create a stage for building the application.
FROM deps as build

# Download additional development dependencies before building, as some projects require
# "devDependencies" to be installed to build. If you don't need this, remove this step.
RUN --mount=type=bind,source=package.json,target=package.json \
    --mount=type=bind,source=package-lock.json,target=package-lock.json \
    --mount=type=cache,target=/root/.npm \
    npm ci

# Copy the rest of the source files into the image.
COPY . .
# Install `serve` to run the application.
RUN npm install -g serve
# Run the build script.
RUN npm run build --omit=dev

################################################################################
# Create a new stage to run the application with minimal runtime dependencies
# where the necessary files are copied from the build stage.
FROM base as final

# Use production node environment by default.
ENV NODE_ENV production

# Run the application as a non-root user.
USER node

# Copy package.json so that package manager commands can be used.
COPY package.json .

# Copy the production dependencies from the deps stage and also
# the built application from the build stage into the image.
COPY --from=deps /usr/src/app/node_modules ./node_modules
COPY --from=build /usr/src/app/build ./build


## Expose the port that the application listens on.
EXPOSE 3000
# Run application # switch between npm start (debug) and serve (for production).
CMD [ "npm", "start" ]
#CMD serve -s build #does not work
#RUN serve -s build #does not work

Backend DockerFile
# syntax=docker/dockerfile:1

# Dockerfile reference guide at
# https://docs.docker.com/go/dockerfile-reference/

################################################################################

# Create a stage for resolving and downloading dependencies.
FROM eclipse-temurin:17-jdk-jammy as deps

WORKDIR /build

# Copy the mvnw wrapper with executable permissions.
COPY --chmod=0755 mvnw mvnw
COPY .mvn/ .mvn/

# Download dependencies as a separate step to take advantage of Docker's caching.
# Leverage a cache mount to /root/.m2 so that subsequent builds don't have to
# re-download packages.
RUN --mount=type=bind,source=pom.xml,target=pom.xml \
    --mount=type=cache,target=/root/.m2 ./mvnw dependency:go-offline -DskipTests

################################################################################

# Create a stage for building the application based on the stage with downloaded dependencies.
# This Dockerfile is optimized for Java applications that output an uber jar, which includes
# all the dependencies needed to run your app inside a JVM. If your app doesn't output an uber
# jar and instead relies on an application server like Apache Tomcat, you'll need to update this
# stage with the correct filename of your package and update the base image of the "final" stage
# use the relevant app server, e.g., using tomcat (https://hub.docker.com/_/tomcat/) as a base image.
FROM deps as package

WORKDIR /build

COPY ./src src/
RUN --mount=type=bind,source=pom.xml,target=pom.xml \
    --mount=type=cache,target=/root/.m2 \
    ./mvnw package -DskipTests && \
    mv target/$(./mvnw help:evaluate -Dexpression=project.artifactId -q -DforceStdout)-$(./mvnw help:evaluate -Dexpression=project.version -q -DforceStdout).jar target/app.jar

################################################################################

# Create a stage for extracting the application into separate layers.
# Take advantage of Spring Boot's layer tools and Docker's caching by extracting
# the packaged application into separate layers that can be copied into the final stage.
# See Spring's docs for reference:
# https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/container-images.html
FROM package as extract

WORKDIR /build

RUN java -Djarmode=layertools -jar target/app.jar extract --destination target/extracted

################################################################################

# Create a new stage for running the application that contains the minimal
# runtime dependencies for the application. This often uses a different base
# image from the install or build stage where the necessary files are copied
# from the install stage.
#
# The example below uses eclipse-turmin's JRE image as the foundation for running the app.
# By specifying the "17-jre-jammy" tag, it will also use whatever happens to be the
# most recent version of that tag when you build your Dockerfile.
# If reproducability is important, consider using a specific digest SHA, like
# eclipse-temurin@sha256:99cede493dfd88720b610eb8077c8688d3cca50003d76d1d539b0efc8cca72b4.
FROM eclipse-temurin:17-jre-jammy AS final

# Create a non-privileged user that the app will run under.
# See https://docs.docker.com/go/dockerfile-user-best-practices/
ARG UID=10001
RUN adduser \
    --disabled-password \
    --gecos "" \
    --home "/nonexistent" \
    --shell "/sbin/nologin" \
    --no-create-home \
    --uid "${UID}" \
    appuser
USER appuser

# Copy the executable from the "package" stage.
COPY --from=extract build/target/extracted/dependencies/ ./
COPY --from=extract build/target/extracted/spring-boot-loader/ ./
COPY --from=extract build/target/extracted/snapshot-dependencies/ ./
COPY --from=extract build/target/extracted/application/ ./

EXPOSE 8080

ENTRYPOINT [ "java", "org.springframework.boot.loader.launch.JarLauncher" ]


Your posted image shows, that both containers are started. So I can only assume, that your frontend container immediately exited and thus is not shown by docker container ls, which shows only running containers per default. Try docker container ls --all which shows all existing (ie also stopped) containers. You could also use docker compose up without the -d option, so you will get all output in your current console, which may give you a hint, why the frontend container exits immediately

What is the output of docker logs container_name

@derpirscher thanks for the tip to remove the -d option. turns out there were multiple errors such as a @babel package not installed during docker build, user permissions error for npm install serve (solved by added USER node), etc. Eventually I managed to debug them, and am able to run my spring-react app with a single docker compose up --build. I will add my new docker related files into the question.
